# Inconsistent highlight colors of swap detection line between vim and neovim

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

I have a question about the highlight group of the warning message `Swap file xxx already exists`. The following is my `.vimrc`/`init.vim` file:

```
colorscheme nord
set termguicolors
```

Now I try to open a file from the terminal which has been opened in another vim/nvim instance. The following is what happens:

In vim
[image]

In neovim
[image]

This is the expected highlight for this message in `nord` colorscheme:
[image]

As you can see, vim displays the warning message in correct highlight colors while neovim does not, even though the RC files are exactly the same in the two cases.

My question is, what caused this behavior difference? Can I achieve the correct highlight behavior for the warning message in neovim?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems NeoVim only applies the theme later in startup, after this message has been printed... Try `nvim --cmd 'colorscheme nord | set termguicolors' a.cc` and it should match the `MoreMsg` highlight group in that case... You might want to open an issue in NeoVim about this. It's possible that the change was introduced on purpose (avoid reading `init.vim` if you'll end up quitting), but ignoring the colorscheme this way looks like the incorrect choice here...

Comment: @filbranden, I tried `nvim --cmd 'colorscheme nord | set termguicolors' a.cc` and the result seems to be the same. `nvim` still does not respect the `MoreMsg` highlight group defined by the `nord` colorscheme. I am using `nvim` 0.5.1 in case the version matters.

Comment: I created [this issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/16750) in the NeoVim github repo to report the problem.